# Spring-boot AwsCrtAsyncHttpClient and NettyNioAsyncHttpClient both in class path

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, httpclient

In my application, I am using a custom implemented AWS SNS module. Within that module, I do create a bean of `AwsCrtAsyncHttpClient` for the `SnsAsyncClient` usage. However, I am getting the following error...

```
nested exception is software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Multiple HTTP implementations were found on the classpath
```

The reason is that, other dependencies such as `AWS CloudWatch`, `S3`, `DynamoDB` and `SQS` has a default implementation of `netty-nio-client` which is `NettyNioAsyncHttpClient`. I had to exclude that dependency in-order to run the application. Is there any other suggestion for me to use `AwsCrtAsyncHttpClient` within the SNS implementation and let `NettyNioAsyncHttpClient` as it is without excluding? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a meaningful response by the following post!
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/3761